# Get paramters and send result to client with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

(I am just learning the ASP.NET MVC 5.)

I want to do a simple thing:

> Just collect 2 numbers and return the divide result.

When in ASP.NET Web Forms, I use Textbox controls within a web form to collect data from client. calculate the result, populate some other web control with the result and send the page to client.

I am trying to do the same thing with ASP.NET MVC 5.

**I think my code is tedious, is there some better or simply other way?**

Controller:

```
public class DivideController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Divide/
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Divide()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Divide(DivideModel model)
    {
        model.Result = model.Arg1 / model.Arg2;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class DivideModel
{
    public float Arg1 { get;set; }
    public float Arg2 { get;set; }
    public float Result { get;set; }
}
```

View:

```
<body>
    <div> 
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
           <div>Arg1:</div>
           <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Arg1)</div>
           <div>Arg2:</div>
           <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Arg2) </div>
           <input type="submit" value="submit" />
       }
    </div>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <div>Result is:</div>
        <div>@Model.Result</div>     
    }
</body>
```

Comment: This looks perfectly okay.  What about it feels tedious to you and perhaps someone can answer that question better.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Just put the input/output parameters in the same model type makes me feel weird.

Comment: then don't have model.Store result in ViewBag and display it in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tedious because your task is so simple.  Like many things, good design adds some overhead at the cost of improved maintenance.  This overhead seems pointless in small programs like this, and in general it is.

Where this overhead pays off is in larger applications where the separation of concerns makes it much easier to make changes without breaking other parts of the code.

I mean, if you wanted to, you could do this task entirely in javascript without writing any server side code.  But you're trying to learn MVC, so for now you should just accept this and move on and learn good habits that will pay off in time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mark - It does answer the question.  Perhaps you should read the whole thing before jumping to conclusions.  The last sentence says that no, there isn't a better or simpler way and that they should just accept that this will pay off in time.